# QR code to dataURL

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am trying to generate a QR code using [davidshimjs/qrcodejs](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs) with the code below. But, when i try to generate DataURL, it gives following error :

**TypeError: document.getElementById(...).toDataURL is not a function**

Below is my code:

**HTML :**

```
<div id="qrcode"></div>
```

**JS :**

```
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode", {
    text: QRId,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
var dataURL = document.getElementById('qrcode').toDataURL();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `toDataURL` only works on the `<canvas>` element.

`canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

### UPDATE

Here is how you would get the data URL...

```js
var QRId = "123456789"
var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode", {
    text: QRId,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    colorDark : "#000000",
    colorLight : "#ffffff",
    correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});

// get the qr div, then find the canvas element inside it
var canvas = document.getElementById('qrcode').querySelector('canvas');

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = dataURL;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/master/qrcode.js"></script>

<div id="qrcode"></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way, i can convert that QRcode to dataURL?

Comment: @ravishankar - see my updated answer. You just have to grab the <canvas> element

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple solution

Include the library in `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>
```

A simple function which converts a text to its equivalent QR image data URL.

```
function textToQrImageDataUrl(txt) {
    var qrDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // This will put a <canvas> inside the given <div> element, and draw
    // the QR image on it
    new QRCode(qrDiv, txt);

    return qrDiv.querySelector('canvas').toDataURL();
}
```

#### Test it in HTML

```
<img id="qrImg" src="#">

<script type="text/javascript">
// This will use the same javascript function that I have defined above
var imgDataUrl = textToQrImageDataUrl("abcd");
document.getElementById('qrImg').setAttribute("src", imgDataUrl);
</script>
```