# Html2canvas - document.getElementById(...).toDataURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers, html2canvas

I would like to take a screenshot of my page.

The initial code I found here:

https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/07/23/html-js-screenshot/

which in my case looks like this:

```
 function makeScreenshot() {
   html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {scale: 2}).then(canvas => {
    canvas.id = "map";
    canvas.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    while (main.firstChild) {
   main.removeChild(main.firstChild); 
    }
    console.log(main);
    main.appendChild(canvas);
   });
  }

  document.getElementById("a-make").addEventListener('click', function()
  {
  document.getElementById("a-make").style.display = "none";
  makeScreenshot();
  document.getElementById("a-download").style.display = "inline";
 }, false);

 document.getElementById("a-download").addEventListener('click', function()
 {

  this.href = document.getElementById("map").toDataURL();
  this.download = "canvas-image.png";
 }, false);
```

and HTML:

```
    <div id="map">
    <div id="screenshot">
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
    </div>
        </div>
    <a id="a-make" href="#">Make a screenshot</a>
    <a id="a-download" href="#" style="display:none;">Download a screenshot</a>
     </div>
```

The console says:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
at index.html:146**

and next

```
**Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).toDataURL is not a function
   at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.html:164)**
```

which is more important I guess, because I can't export my screenshot.

I found some solution here:

[QR code to dataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900628/qr-code-to-dataurl)

and tried to implement into my code:

```
     canvas.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

just underneath the

```
     canvas.id = "map";

     and

     var canvas = document.getElementById('map').querySelector('canvas');
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

just above the

```
     this.href = document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = dataURL();
     this.download = "canvas-image.png";
     }, false);
```

The fiddle is here

https://jsfiddle.net/kyzLfur3/

[image]

Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: The <div> element does not have the toDataURL method. It's a `canvas`'s method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [toDataURL() not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467080/todataurl-not-a-function)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley - Not really, the OP's `id="map"` element isn't even a `canvas`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id="map"` element is a `div`. They don't have `toDataURL`. [`canvas` elements do](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvas-todataurl), but not `div`s.

Elsewhere in the question you show code looking for a `canvas` *within* that `div`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('map').querySelector('canvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

So if at some point a `canvas` gets added to the `#map` `div`, you might want to add that to your `click` handler:

```
document.getElementById("a-download").addEventListener('click', function()
{
 this.href = document.getElementById("map").querySelector('canvas').toDataURL();
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
 this.download = "canvas-image.png";
}, false);
```

Comment: I think your code is working. Unfortunately in my case the console throws:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>
which is driven by the offline version of the map.

Comment: @MKR - Yeah, that's because the canvas is cross-origin and not served with CORS headers that would let you access it from your origin.